# call the gmapping or amcl package myself

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I want to write a program myself with calling the gmapping or amcl package, then run it,rarther than in ROS.How can I use the package,is there any file tell me how to use it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149901/call-the-gmapping-or-amcl-package-myself/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get a "ROS free" version of gmapping from [openslam.org](https://openslam.org/). For AMCL, I´m not sure if a standalone is available (originally [AMCL was a player driver](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Player-2.0.0/player/group__driver__amcl.html), so that´d be a ROS free version). It would be pretty relatively easy to strip the AMCL [CMakeLists.txt/package](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/hydro-devel/amcl) of ROS related parts though.

Note that this site is called ROS Answers though, so using these packages without ROS is really beyond the scope of it ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0